# Where should I ask AI related questions?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, site-recommendation

Since the artificial intelligence SE website was already proposed ([AI.SE](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/57719/artificial-intelligence)) but has been closed because it didn't have enough activity, where should AI related questions be asked?

An example of a question is: "What reinforcement learning algorithms are best suited when world state is not know, but has to be estimated using particle filters?".

Should I use stack-overflow?

Comment: Oh, I thought you said "**AL**-related questions". I don't think I need an entire Stack Exchange site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Computer Science (Beta) SE](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [Cross Validated SE](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) have room for artificial intelligence questions. If you are uncertain about them, ask on their Meta.

On Cross Validated SE (which I participate), artificial intelligence questions are more related to the subfield of 'machine learning', despite there are also place for other subfields (discussed on this [post](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2094/where-should-i-ask-a-question-about-artificial-intelligence)).

It helps if the AI question fits the Stack Exchange Q/A format, it is not too broad and it is not primarily opinion-based.

Answer (score 1):

There is new restart of [Artificial Intelligence SE](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/93481/artificial-intelligence/visit) which started private beta last week.

[image]

Currently it has variety of questions and it aims to *bring people from this one particular field, which exists in between all above in one place*.

Answer (score 0):

There is also https://datascience.stackexchange.com/, for more applied AI questions.